# How to subtract two django dates in template

Tags: python, django, date, django-templates

I want to get the number of days between **today** and a model field **end_date**.
I defined today in my view as shown below.
I will then use the number of days to check if its less than or equal to 50 which will add a class to the `<td></td>` element

**MY TEMPLATE**

```
{% for instance in queryset %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
        <td>{{instance.empnumber}}</td>
        <td>{{instance.name}}</td>
        <td>{{instance.be}}</td>
        <td>{{instance.status}}</td>
        {% if (today - instance.end_date) <= 50 %}
            <td class="highlight">{{instance.start_date}}</td>
            <td class="highlight">{{instance.end_date}} : {{ instance.end_date|timeuntil:today }}</td>
        {% else %}
            <td>{{instance.status_start_date}}</td>
            <td>{{instance.status_end_date}}</td>
        {% endif %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

**MY VIEW**

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    queryset = Employee.objects.all().order_by('-last_updated')
    today = date.today()
    context = {
        "queryset": queryset,
        "today": today,
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I would make a method on the Employee object.

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    ...
    def ends_within_50_days(self):
        return (date.today() - self.end_date).days <= 50
```

Now you can just do:

```
{% if instance.ends_within_50_days %}
```

Comment: The method name is `ends_within_50_days`. This would mean that the entry will end at some point from today within the next 50 days. However the method checks if the entry ended within the last 50 days. Do you think that renaming the method would be beneficial for the code readabilty and maintainability?

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the previous answer, you could make a method, or I'd go with property, in your model class.

Assuming that you have something like this:

```
from datetime import date
from django.db import models

class Employee(models.Model):
    end_date = models.DateField()
    # ... rest ...

    @property
    def age_in_days(self):
        today = date.today()
        result = self.end_date - today
        return result.days
```

In your template you can check if it is less than 50 days old:

```
{% if instance.age_in_days <= 50 %}
```

The property `age_in_days` will return the difference in days between today and the value of `end_date` as an integer. This should give you more flexibility in case you want to check not only if it is less than 50 days old. Eventually that requirement might change. Then you could reuse the property without refactoring your models.

You can still define a method in your model class to check if the instance ended within the last 50 days:

```
def ended_in_the_last_50_days(self):
    return self.age_in_days <= 50
```

Comment: This worked for me, but had to change `result = end_date - today` to `result = self.end_date - today`

Comment: @MattG thanks for the correction, I edited the answer.